# GET http://localhost:8080/static/css/1.e8747c0d.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: css, reactjs, spring-boot

I can reference index.html but not the contents from static such as css and js

```
<build>
    <finalName>LoginAndRegistration</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v10.15.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.4.0</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy todir="${basedir}/target/classes/resources">
                                <filesetdir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build"/>
                            </copy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I tried many combinations of adding `<copy todir="${basedir}/target/classes/resources">` like public, static, resources etc nothing seems to be working.

I can reference index.html with http://localhost:8080/LoginAndRegistration/ but it's not loading the css and javascript

Comment: Unclear what your question is. Please provide a [mcve]. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Post your error stack